# Error manpath can't set the locale in my elementary OS Freya

Tags: release-freya, greeter

I'm using elementary OS for months with no problem (don't installed nothing and uninstall anything, same apps for months). But yesterday I rebooted my computer, typed my password to login and pressed enter, and then got into infinite login loop. I tried with terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and when I login I saw this:

```
manpath: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

Tried with sudo apt-get update, and sudo apt-get upgrade but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try resetting your locales with:

```
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall locales
```

If that doesn't work, you might try to reinstall them with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: I don't know if was this but I type ' sudo apt-get install --reinstall locales and then restart my computer, enter in recovery mode, run sudo apt-get update && upgrade and restart again and the problem was solve, thanks